# Debugging react-hot-loader webpack boilerplate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have been trying to get a ReactJS Hotloader working.

Specifically, even [this boilerplate demo](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate) does not work for me: I run `npm start`, I see "hello world" text in my browser, I see "[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled" in my browser console, but when I edit and save the 'hello world' text in App.js the changes are not auto-rendered.

In this [troubleshooting page](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.md), I fall under this category:

> I see “[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled” but nothing happens when
>   I edit App.js
>
> If you're running Node 0.11.13, you might want to try updating to
>   0.12. Some people reported this helped solve this problem. Also make sure that your requires have the same filename casing as the files.
>   Having App.js and doingrequire('app') might trip the watcher on some
>   systems.
>
> OS X also has a rarely-occuring bug that causes some folders to get
>   'broken' with regards to file system change monitoring. Here are some
>   suggested fixes.

I am running Node 5.6.0 on OSX. I am only trying the boilerplate code from the repository linked above, so the filename casing is all the same as the files. I have tried restarting my machine.

Anything else I could try to get React hot-loading working? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "does not work?"

Comment: Is your app in a VM like vagrant / virtual box?

Comment: @Mathletics: I have clarified the behavior that I see when trying to run the boilerplate demo. Sorry if I was not clear enough.

Comment: @azium: Nope, not running in a VM. And not making any code changes to boilerplate linked above. Just trying to get the most basic react hotloading demo working on my machine. Thanks all !

Comment: Are you trying to hot reload a functional component?

Comment: @azium: yes, I am indeed trying to configure my react/webpack setup to hot reload functional components. Specifically, in this case I'm trying to update the text in src/App.js contained in the boilerplate demo linked above (this one: https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate). Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eureka! After many weeks of this causing trouble, I discovered that the issue was related to me backing up my code using Dropbox desktop. Perhaps Dropbox change syncing was conflicting with Webpack polling, or something of that sort.

Hope this will spare someone else the frustration I went through!